# Which port is my ASP.NET Core 6 app running on in AWS Fargate

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I just did the following:

1. Created an ASP.NET Core 6 API in Visual Studio with the docker option selected
2. Built the docker image
3. Uploaded the image to AWS ECR
4. Crated a cluster, task definition and service

Now I can see my task running, but I don't know how to connect to the API. Port 80 and 443 don't do anything and neither do 7260 and 5260, which are used locally for debugging.

Below is my current config for everything (I got desperate and added all sorts of ports I was hoping might be relevant).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 7260
EXPOSE 49159
EXPOSE 5260
...
```

launchSettings.json in the project:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57003",
      "sslPort": 44385
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "CoffeSubscription": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7260;http://localhost:5260",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  }
}
```

Port mappings on task definition:

[image]

Task ENI security group settings (Allow everything from everywhere [Yes, for testing only]):

[image]

If anybody has any advice I'd be immensely grateful.

**EDIT**

I managed to set the port the app starts on by adding the following to my Dockerfile

```
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:80;https://*:443"
```

Thanks everybody your comments pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you create a simple index.html file and check if your browser can open it?

Comment: How are you checking that it works? I ask because a common misconception is to use Swagger, but Swagger is disabled by default in a container based on the MS aspnet image.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to pass the following environment variable into your Fargate service, so you can manage the port your application lives on:

```
ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

*In this example will your application be exposed on **port 8080***

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html